Understanding AWS Nitro and AWS KMS
I'm reading about AWS Nitro Enclaves and understand that AWS KMS can verify that the enclave is not compromised and perform necessary functions.
However, what if the ec2 interfacing with the enclave is compromised? It can still interface with the enclave and get the necessary functions performed.
